# Analogy of Levi-Civita contraction exists?

Tags: tensor-calculus

In three dimensions we know $$
\epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{mnk} =\delta_{im} \delta_{jn} - \delta_{in}\delta_{jm}. \tag{1}
$$
Is there any known three index object $\alpha_{ijk}$ such that $$
\alpha_{ijk} \alpha_{mnk} =\delta_{im} \delta_{jn} + \delta_{in}\delta_{jm}~?\tag{2}
$$

Comment: Not directly an answer, but I think $\alpha_{ijk}$ would be related to the so-called [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)) of a matrix (in the same way that $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is related to the determinant). It's worth noting that unlike the determinant, the permanent is not invariant under unitary transformations, so $\alpha_{ijk}$ won't be a tensor.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 3):

In $N$ dimensions define $N$-vectors
$$\vec{\alpha}_{ij}=(\alpha_{ij,1}, \ldots , \alpha_{ij,N})^T, \quad i,j~\in~\{1,\ldots, n\}.$$
We assume for simplicity that $\alpha_{ijk}\in\mathbb{R}$ are real. Then OP's eq. (2) becomes
$$ \vec{\alpha}_{ij}\cdot \vec{\alpha}_{mn} ~=~\delta_{im} \delta_{jn} + \delta_{in}\delta_{jm}.\tag{2}$$
This implies that there are at least $\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$ orthogonal vectors $\vec{\alpha}_{ij}$ with $1\leq i\leq j\leq N$ in $N$ dimensions, which in turn implies that $N\leq 1$, i.e. OP's eq. (2) is only possible in $N=1$ dimension.

Conversely, for $N=1$, there are 2 solutions: $\alpha_{111}=\pm \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate why the expression you defined is not a tensor?

Comment: To be more explicit, how would I *prove* that the expression you have is NOT a tensor. 

In my mind I could write $$ \alpha_{i'j'k'}= R_{i'}{}^i R_{j'}{}^j R_{k'}{}^k \alpha_{ijk} $$  where $R$ represents some Rotation or Translation in 3D Euclidean, and now $\alpha$ seems to transform just fine. My expectation then is that the relation asked in the question would still hold since everything would just transform appropriately.

Comment: @FredrikSy The definition implies that the given form for $\alpha_{ijk}$ holds in all coordinate systems - the $\alpha$ with primed indices should be equal to the $\alpha$ without primed indices, and your equation won't hold in that case.

Comment: @Javier, I understand that the components of $\alpha$ would be different depending on the coordinate system st the defn that Qmechanic gave is particular to a coordinate system and so $\alpha_{i'j'k'} \ne \alpha_{ijk}$. However while the definition would not hold in a different coordinate system (called say $\mu'$), equation (2) (from the question) would still hold right? It's just that expression for the components for $\alpha$ would now be different from Qmechanic 's answer. Wouldn't $\alpha$ still be a tensor though, only in a different coordinate system?

Comment: @FredrikSy You have it backwards. Yes, eq (2) would hold, but the components of $\alpha$ are the *same* in every coordinate system (by definition). And if the components are the same in every coordinate system then the transformation law form your previous comment won't hold, unless $\alpha$ is the Levi-Civita symbol (which it isn't).

Comment: @Javier , thanks I think I get it now. This all hinges on the defn implying that the components are invariant (which of course it's not unless it's the Levi-Civita). Would you say then that $\alpha$ could still be a tensor solution to the eq(2) provided that the definition is for a particular $i,j,k$. Would that be meaningful? I'd like to emphasize that I'm proposing we change the defn of $\alpha$ here to be the components for a particular coordinate system only.

Comment: @Javier A possibly better rephrasing of my question is, If a tensor $\alpha$ has components obeying Qmechanics answer in *some* coordinate $\mu$, then it should obey eq(2) in any coordinate system because eq(2) would only have tensors.

Comment: Wait, the answer seems not right. @Qmechanic Try i=j=1, m=2, n=3. Then left hand side is nonzero while the right hand side is zero.

Comment: @tiyan Li. You're right. I updated the answer.